# Defining a procedure given a predicate in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Given a predicate that tests a single item, such as `positive?`, I am trying to create an `all-are` version of it for testing whether all elements of the list satisfy the predicate

Ex:
`((all-are positive?) '(1 2 3 4)) => #t`
`((all-are even?) '(2 4 5 6 8)) => #f`

`all-are` should take a predicate as an argument and return a new *function* that can be applied to the list of elements

Comment: Please explain what problem you are having with this.  It's not clear what you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite simple to express in terms of an existing procedure: `andmap` - which returns `#t` if a given predicate, when applied to all the elements in a list, evaluates to true for all of them:

```
(define ((all-are predicate) lst)
  (andmap predicate lst))
```

I'm using a bit of syntactic sugar for returning a curried procedure, because the question states that a *function* must be returned. It works as expected:

```
((all-are positive?) '(1 2 3 4))
> #t

((all-are even?) '(2 4 5 6 8))
> #f
```

I'm guessing that you have to implement the procedure from scratch, and not using existing procedures as in my solution. A good exercise would be to turn the short version above (which demonstrates the general idea of what needs to be done) into something simpler using only basic forms - that's probably what your teacher expects from you.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to only use the basics of 'foldr',
the code turns out to be:

```
(define (all-are pred l)
   (foldr (λ (x y)
      (and y (pred x))) #t l))
```

Try to use foldr, foldl and other basics and figure out the necessary parameters, this will be a good programming practice....Hope it helps!!!